# get location (row and column) of an element in grid layout of JLabels java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, grid-layout

I have a `JPanel` with a 10x10 `GridLayout` of `JLabels`, and when the user clicks one of those labels, I want to be able to get the row and column of the cell they clicked (or the index in the layout, if thats more convenient). If anyone knows how to do this, or has any suggestions, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use composition and wrap this structure into a POJO with each label having a registered `MouseListener`...it's a basic manager object, or maybe use a `JTable`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!...a short example would be great for a newcomer to this topic, if you wouldn't mind. :)

Comment: @iphonedev7: for JTables, please look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). 1+ to mre.

Comment: So I think I have this correct, but feel free to correct me...so I create a `JTable` and then add it to the `JPanel`?

Answer (score 1):

when you create the labels, you can use their 'name' property to hold an ID

```
for(int x ....)
{
  ...
  label[x] = new JLabel(...);
  label[x].setName(String.valueOf(x));//<------------
  ...
}
```

if you getSource() via mouseListener, you can then cast source to JLabel then label.getName()

which will return a String that can be parsed to an int.